# tailwindcss dynamic border-color using template string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css

I'm using react 18, nextjs 13 with tailwindcss, postcss, autoprefixer

expect: clicking the button to toggle border-color and other styles
behavior: all styles toggle except border-color

question: why doesn't border-color behave the same way as the other styles?

broken code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const [dark, darkSet] = useState(true)
  function handleClick() {
    darkSet((prev) => !prev)
  }

  const bgColor = 'bg-' + (dark ? 'black' : 'white')
  const textColor = 'text-' + (dark ? 'white' : 'black')
  const borderColor = 'border-' + (dark ? 'white' : 'black')
  const borderStyle = 'border-' + (dark ? 'solid' : 'dashed')

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div className={`flex min-h-screen min-w-screen `}>
          <div
            className={`${bgColor} ${textColor} border-8 ${borderStyle} ${borderColor}`}
          >
            Get started by editing
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleClick} className="h-8 bg-red-500">
            theme
          </button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 const bgColor = 'bg-' + (dark ? 'black' : 'white')
  const textColor = 'text-' + (dark ? 'white' : 'black')
  const borderColor = 'border-' + (dark ? 'white' : 'black')
  const borderStyle = 'border-' + (dark ? 'solid' : 'dashed')
```

to

```
 const bgColor = dark ? 'bg-black' : 'bg-white'
  const textColor = dark ? 'text-white' : 'text-black'
  const borderColor = dark ? 'border-white' : 'border-black'
  const borderStyle = dark ? 'border-solid' : 'border-dashed'
```

---

### Explanation:

#### Is it recommended to use `dynamic class` in `tailwind` ?

##### No

Using `dynamic classes` in `tailwind-css` is usually not recommended because `tailwind` uses `tree-shaking` i.e any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

Hence it is always recommended to use ***full class names***

According to [Docs][1]

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

#### Isn't there work around ?

##### Yes

As a last resort, Tailwind offers [Safelisting classes][2].

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

You can use [regular expressions][3] to include all the colors you want using `pattern`

###### Note:  You can force Tailwind to create `variants` as well:

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue|orange)/, // You can display all the colors that you need
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],      // Optional
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for fleshing this out a bit but I still don't understand why the `border-<non-black/white-color>` doesn't work.

Comment: As i have mentioned in the answer,  `tailwind uses tree-shaking i.e any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.`. So you have to declare `border-<non-black/white-color>` explicitly somewhere in the code. Then it works

Comment: wow thanks! ok, so I had defined the `border-red-900 dark:border-white` utility classes in a file at `/styles/styles.js` and exported it to the `/pages/index.js` (this is a nextjs pages style app).

Comment: `styles.js` was not included in the `content` field of `tailwind.config.js` so it wasn't seeing the class defined in the code. I just added `/styles/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` to the config and now the border color is being picked up on.

Comment: that is awesome to here

Answer (score 1):

update: this still doesn't work for colors other than black/white, what is going on here?

solution: as per tailwindcss docs

> Don't construct class names dynamically

> Always use complete class names

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

working code:

```
// ...
  const bgColor = dark ? 'bg-black' : 'bg-white'
  const textColor = dark ? 'text-white' : 'text-black'
  const borderColor = dark ? 'border-white' : 'border-black'
  const borderStyle = dark ? 'border-solid' : 'border-dashed'
// ...
```

the difference is that the entire utility class is conditionally constructed then inserted into the template string literal in the jsx `className` attribute.

question: I still want to know why this `border-color` case is different as I've run into a few cases like this when conditionally constructing the utility classes.

Comment: I suspect it is working because you are using those colors elsewhere so they are already being picked up by tailwind. Please show the code that is not working, I expect that safeclassing the correct regex pattern will make your template string class composition work. For example, I dynamically generate opacity-* values and it works because I force tailwind to pre-generate all opacity-* options with:

    safelist: [
        {
          pattern: /opacity(-[0-9]{1,3})/,
        },
    ]